# HR employee attrition modeling - making a balanced sample question

Tags: regression, data, sampling

I have dataset 1 (stayers) consisting of 1500 record of HR data demographic data of employees (11 features) who currently are in the company. Dataset 2 (leavers) contains 180 records -same features- contains demographic data of people who voluntarily left the company.

My aim is to identify within dataset 1 who is at risk of leaving the company.

Question: what would be a good approach to build a training data set?
I am thinking about some kind of train_test_split

My thinking is right now to split stayers (dataset 1) into 8 groups of roughly 180 records large groups
then combining each of these groups individually with the complete dataset 2 (leavers) build a logistic regression

With each of these combinations I do a logistic regression on the remaining stayers data and do a prediction on attrition (yes/no) and then compare all the resulting models

What do you think? Any glaring pitfalls or risks in my approach?

Comment: One very important consideration in the whole idea itself is that you need to understand the ethics behind making such a model. Yes, it would be beneficial in a way to identify these individuals and ensure that they do not leave the business if appropriate. But this sort of model can also unnecessarily disadvantage individuals. Even worse if this model were to be applied in the recruitment process as you would then exclude applicants who are predicted to leave the business, but might be your most loyal employees. I recommend you take all of this into consideration before advancing.

Comment: yes, you are right. That's why I will have to present my results to an ethics commission before doing anything else with it